# IntelliJ can't find custom library [Maven]

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, import, package

When i was writing my first "real" java project (a todo app in console), I realised i use a lot of methods that could be easily made into my very own library (simple Maven project). I added the root folder to my main procejt with File>Project Structure>Modules>Dependencies>Java and selected the root folder - Toolbox. But when i type

```
import org.toolbox.Tools.*;
```

it is all good and the usages are fine but it fails to compile.
First the error message:

```
Error:(5, 19) java: package org.toolbox does not exist
Error:(6, 25) java: package org.toolbox.Tools does not exist
Error:(10, 69) java: package Tools does not exist
Error:(13, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Tools
  location: class org.todo.ToDo
Error:(13, 27) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Tools
  location: class org.todo.ToDo
Error:(16, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class STATE
  location: class org.todo.ToDo
Error:(18, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable STATE
  location: class org.todo.ToDo
```

Now a screenshot of my dependencies
[image: dependencies]

IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2019.3.1
JDK 11.0.1
Manjaro Linux

Any help would be greatly appreciated

As requested, the pom.xml of todo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.todo</groupId>
    <artifactId>TO-DO</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

and the pom.xml of my library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.toolbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>Toolbox</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    // because i was getting an error with maven compiler defaulting to        1.5
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the library project too a maven project (with it's own group, artifact id and version).
Than add to the dependancy of other maven projects.
(This would wourk both inside and outside the IDE)

Once you start with maven, keep going with maven, try to add dependancies :

You must install the dependancy with maven (either from command line or from the IDE) running 'mvn clean install' (this is basic for packaging system like maven).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.todo</groupId>
<artifactId>TO-DO</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <!-- try to add dependancies -->
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.toolbox</groupId>
                <artifactId>Toolbox</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                       <release>11</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: The problem is when i try to type int the artifact id "Toolbox" it can't find mine. I think it looks only for the big public ones.

Comment: @KamilSuhak You should either your Toolbox imported as maven project as well or you have it build (in the proper version) in your local maven repo. Would be helpful to see pom.xml of both projects

Comment: @KamilSuhak You must install the dependancy with maven (either from command line or from the IDE) running 'mvn clean install' (this is basic for packaging system like maven). Don't give up so easily, a packaging system like maven is very useful for automatize build, configuration and release tasks

Comment: @KamilSuhak Have you ever thought of eclipse? I don't want to start a war but it seems to me maven integration is better (especially you could use other maven dependancies in your workspace without building them anytime you make a change)

Comment: I'm new to maven so i don't knwo which one is better for that but i like to have the same brand for just about everything. I have the jetbrains student suite so i just use their IDEs